# Processing data from the Linkedin API via django

Tags: python, django, api, linkedin-api

I'm trying to figure out how to precisely access the linkedin API using Django and be able to do something with the data. Using [this page](https://github.com/ozgur/python-linkedin) as a starter is good - but it's not entirely clear on how I pass on this data to my views so I can render it to my templates. In a similar vein, not entirely clear on how I pass this data to my database.

Comment: What exactly you want to do?, show us like a pseudo-code or something.

Comment: `from linkedin import linkedin authentication = linkedin.LinkedInDeveloperAuthentication(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, USER_TOKEN, USER_SECRET, RETURN_URL, linkedin.PERMISSIONS.enums.values()) application = linkedin.LinkedInApplication(authentication) application.get_profile()

`So after this something like:

`def view_function(request):
`getusername = linkedin.profile().name

`Class Database(0):
`username.save()

Comment: My apologies for the formatting, I'm pretty new to SO's standard.

Comment: Do you only want to access your profile? Where in database do you want to save the user data?

Comment: here's an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18855148/linkedin-authentication#answer-25237894