# LinkedIn Authentication

Tags: python, django, authentication, oauth, linkedin-api

Authentication is failing
I'm trying without success to get my users signed into LinkedIn via Oauth authentication in Python. I'm using Django in python and not using any third party social authentication. I'm using the Guide to gain access to the API using Python and Django. However I am having trouble getting the Access Token. I can get the user logged in and get the Authentication Code. I have placed a new request as the earlier question was far too convoluted. You can see that here: [Performing POST on a URL string in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18279865/performing-post-on-a-url-string-in-django)

Nothing was resolved and still unsure if this is an issue with LinkedIn or the code. LinkedIn have not been particularly helpful here, sadly.

but after getting the Author code, I simply cannot get the access token. I'm getting a 400 error for everything and despite getting the author code, on posting as the documentation suggests, I get the following:

```
u'oauth_problem=parameter_absent&oauth_parameters_absent=oauth_consumer_key%26oauth_signature%26oauth_signature_method%26oauth_token%26oauth_timestamp%26oauth_verifier'
```

I'm enclosing my Python code here in its entirety in the hope that someone can spot what is going wrong.

```
import oauth2 as oauth
import httplib2
import time, os, simplejson
import urllib
import urllib2
import pycurl
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve
#from django.core.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django import forms
from django.utils import timezone
import urlparse
import requests

consumer_key = 'Yours'
consumer_secret = 'Yours'
user_token = 'Yours'
user_secret = 'Yours'

consumer = oauth.Consumer(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
access_token = oauth.Token(key=user_token,secret=user_secret)
client = oauth.Client(consumer, access_token)
request_token_url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken'
access_token_url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/accessToken'
authorize_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authenticate'

def login(request):

redirect_uri = urllib2.quote('http://127.0.0.1:9000/loginsuccess')

codeURL = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=c3skrqz5wqmm&scope=r_fullprofile&state=DCEEFWF45453sdffef425&redirect_uri=" + redirect_uri

# Fill the keys and secrets you retrieved after registering your app

# Use your API key and secret to instantiate consumer object

#resp,content = client.request("http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?format=json", "GET", "")

#resp, content = client.request(request_token_url, "POST")
#request_token = dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(content))
#return HttpResponse(access_token)

return HttpResponseRedirect(codeURL)

def loginsuccess(request):
authcode = request.GET.get('code')
redirect_uri = 'http://www.jelt.com'
#redirect_succ = 'http://www.127.0.0.1:8080/manage'

postdata = {
'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
'code': authcode,
'redirect_uri': redirect_uri,
'client_id': consumer_key,
'client_secret': consumer_secret,
}

r = requests.post(access_token_url, data=postdata)

#return HttpResponse(r.text)
#return HttpResponse(r.status_code)

return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_uri)

def Manage(request):
return HttpResponseRedirect('http://www.xyz.com')

def success(request):
redirect_uri = urllib2.quote('http://www.xyz.com')
redirect_uri = "http://www.xyz.com"
return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_uri)
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason not to use a Python wrapper ? https://github.com/ozgur/python-linkedin

Comment: Or instead of the wrapper how about Django-Social-Auth? https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `login` code is redirecting to the OAuth 2.0 endpoint `https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization` but your callback `loginsuccess` is trying to fetch the OAuth 1.0a token from `https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/accessToken`. You need to update your `access_token_url` to the OAuth 2.0 endpoint `https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken` per the [LinkedIn docs](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication).

Comment: Dooh! Thanks, I didn't spot that - got it sorted now. Many thanks for the extra pair of eyes. I'm petitioning LinkedIn to create a full working copy in Python as many people are having lots of issues.

Comment: Shameless plug, not official from linkedin but works nicely - http://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/linkedin.html